# PIP Value conversion - How can I convert my Pips? general formula

Tags: finance, fx, currency, cross-currency-basis, spot-rate

So I was wondering, how I can convert for example a 20 pips charge is(Spot: 1.0250 with pips 1.0270) on EURUSD into EURCNH Pips with (Spot EURCNH at 7.3005). Is there a general formula and  short-cut?

Thinking from Trader perspective and someone wants to buy

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider your treasury account is in EUR (you have to change your P&L on a spot transactions into EUR each time). Let's suppose this is done at the current spot price in the market, following your transaction.
Let's consider the below example :
[image]

Suppose a FOR/DOM quotation (1 units of FOR accounts for S units of DOM, FOR is EUR, DOM is USD or CNH).
20 pips in EUR/USD change over 1mio EUR returns a P&L of 2000 USD, or 1951.22 EUR if converted at 1.0250 to get your treasury back in EUROS.

20 pips in EUR/CNH over 1mio EUR returns a P&L of 2000 CNH, or 273.97 EUR if converted at 7.3000 to get your treasury back in EUROS.

Therefore, you can easily see that the P&L in the DOM (alternative, priced currency) is the same : 2000 units, but what changes is to spot rate you will use to get back in FOR currency.

Notice : 7.3000 / 1.0250 = 7.1220 gives you the USD/CNH rate, which is the link between your two P&L, you can see it as a ratio, or non-arbitrage equivalence between both.

So 20 pips in EUR/USD <=> 20pips in EUR/CNH * 7.1220.
So a spread of 0.01424 pips in EURCNH, is equivalent to 20 pips in EUR USD.

To make it even shorter, think that CNH has a lower value against EUR and the FX rate is approx 7 times higher, so you need to take 7 times the same spread to get the same P&L.

If you were trying to convert EURUSD pips into EURNOK pips, i would tell you to take approximately 10 times the spread (so 200 pips on en EURNOK transaction)

I hope it is clear